# how to use file upload in jquery modal popup?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have created jquery modal popup with post back events using bellow code

```
<div id="divPopup" style="display: none">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlLessonDetails" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>

            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>

$('#divPopup').parent().appendTo($('#aspnetForm'));
$('#divPopup').parent().before($(".ui-widget-overlay,ui-front"));
```

I need to use file upload in that jquery modal popup. but in here i cannot make full page full postback to upload a file. Please give me any solution.